# Adding full programamticly custom view to ViewController. AutoLayout problems

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I really can't understand how to use layout when create custom view.

Main problem is in here:

```
rect.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
rect.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 1),
```

If I use multiplier it's work correctly. But if if I use constant:

```
rect.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.frame.width)
```

it's doesn't working.

How can I use any superView frame sizes for my custom view autoLayout constraint?

```
class MainView: UIView {

    lazy var rect: UIView  = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = .red
        layout()

    }

    func layout() {

        addSubview(rect)

        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

           NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            rect.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
            rect.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 1),
               rect.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
               rect.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor)
           ])

       }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    let mainView = MainView(frame: .zero)

    override func loadView() {

        self.view = mainView
    }
```

Comment: when your created `MainView` you set it to .zero, how can your child view have any better frame if you use `rect.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.frame.width)`?

Comment: I'm trying set mainView.frame = view.frame before self.view= mainView, but it doesn't change result

Answer (score 0):

> If I use multiplier it's work correctly. But if if I use constant:
>   `rect.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.frame.width)`

This is bound to happen, In your viewController you instantiate your `mainView` as
`let mainView = MainView(frame: .zero)` This will trigger `init` of `MainView` with frame as zero

You call layout inside `init`

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    backgroundColor = .red
    layout()

}
```

so you essentially call layout when `MainView` frame is `Zero` At this point if you set `rect.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.frame.width)` then what you are essentially saying is `rect.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)`
hence width is set to zero

Please read the statement carefully, you are setting your rect width anchor to a **constant** which is 0 in this case, so even when in future stages of UI cycle your `MainView` gets proper width, your rect's width will always be zero because you set it to constant 0 value.

> But I set mainView.frame = view.frame before self.view= mainView

Unfortunately for your rect this statement comes little late :) layout was called in init of mainView and hence rects width anchor was already set to a constant 0. Now though you update mainView.frame, your rect will never bother to update its width, why will it? It has its constraints already resolved to a constant value which is obviously '**0**' in this case :)

**`rect.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 1)`,Why this works?**

Here you say your rect's width anchor to be equal to width anchor of your `MainView`, you are not setting rect's width anchor to a constant rather, you are setting it to match the width anchor of MainView, so when MainView's frame finally sets to a proper value, your rect will also updates its width to match MainViews width.

Quite frankly `multiplier: 1` makes no sense in this case, as you are trying to match the width of your rect to match the width of your MainView, if you want your rect's width to vary proportionally to width of MainView (like 50% of MainView width etc etc) only then multiplier makes sense

Autolayout constraints are nothing more than mathematical equations, understanding/visualising  them properly is the key to get perfect UI with constraint

Hope this helps

Comment: OK. Now it's more accessibly for me. If I'm understand correctly there are no way to use (equalTo: constant) where constant is computed property that using superView frame size for calculation. Or there some way to init frame by size of superView?

Comment: Best solution that I find is make frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use any superView frame sizes for my custom view autoLayout constraint?

Simply remove multiplayer.

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        rect.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor),
        rect.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor),
        rect.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
        rect.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor)
        ])
```